# To what extent does the ruling of imitating the kuffaar apply to?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, hadith-interpretation, kuffar

It was narrated that Ibn ‘Umar said: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘Whoever imitates a people is one of them.’” (Narrated by Abu Dawood, al-Libaas, 3512. Al-Albaani said in Saheeh Abi Dawood, (it is) hasan saheeh. No. 3401).

This means imitating them in what they do like if they celebrate Christmas and we celebrate it because they are is haram.

To what extent does this apply to?

Does it mean you can't wear the same clothes as them even though where you live only has those kind of clothes? Does that mean eating the same food as them is haram? Does it mean you shouldn't go to school because that's what they do?

Comment: Relevant posts https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37158/does-he-who-imitates-any-people-is-one-of-them-mean-im-chinese (I think my answer here already answers your question), https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36983/how-to-distinguish-imitation-from-doing-the-same-thing, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36929/to-what-extent-are-reverts-required-to-avoid-behaving-like-non-muslims