# Can a lefty eat (with spoon) with his left hand?

Tags: fiqh

Assalamu-alaikum, 
I am by born Muslim and left handed person. I write with left hand, use computer mouse in left hand and do many more daily life things with left hand (a lefty- people says). I eat with my right hand. But I cannot eat such foods that require fork, spoon with my right hand. I have to use my left hand.

I have trouble holding pen, spoon etc. and maneuvering them with right hand.
I want to know what sharia says about eating for people like me (a left-handed person).


Jazāk Allāhu Khayran

Comment: To answer this we need to check first whether using a spoon is lawful at all! See for example [Is there a consensus that eating with a knif and fork as in western culture is unlawful](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36625/is-there-a-consensus-that-eating-with-a-knife-and-fork-as-in-western-culture-i/36654#36654)